# date_query won't accept day parameter, but will accept month and year for a custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, date-query

I have a frustrating issue. I am using the `date_query` as referenced in the Codex:

```
<?php
$today = getdate();
$args = array(
'post_type'         => 'Lighting',
'post_status'       => 'publish',
'posts_per_page'    => 1,
'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $today['year'],
            'month' => $today['mon'],
            'day'   => $today['mday'],
        ),
    ),
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

While I can display custom posts as expected if I exclude `'day'`, I get no posts when it is included in the query. I am using *Advanced Custom Fields Pro* with the `date-picker`. I have no idea why this is happening, and I've searched tirelessly to determine why my `date_query` is not working.  I am able to echo the date, so I don't understand where the disconnect is.

/****** RESPONSE TO ANSWERS ******/

Thanks for the responses.  I have done a meta_query with what I think is the proper date format, but I am still unable to query only today's post. Here is the new query:

```
<?php // Let's get the data we need to loop through below

$args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'carillon', // Tell WordPress which post type we want
        'orderby' => 'meta_value', // We want to organize the events by date    
        'meta_key' => 'date_of_lighting', // Grab the "date_of_event" field created via "date-picker" plugin (stored in ‘YYYYMMDD’)
        'posts_per_page' => '1', // Let's show just one post.   
        'meta_query' => array( // WordPress has all the results, now, return only the event on today's date
            array(
                'key' => 'date_of_lighting', // Check the s"date_of_lighting field
                'value' => date("Y-M-D"), // Set today's date (note the similar format)
                'compare' => '=', // Return only today's post
                'type' => 'NUMERIC' // Let WordPress know we're working with numbers
                )
            )
    );
```

Any suggestions? Thanks, again.

/******** SOLUTION **********/

Hi Everyone,

So, I found a solution that works. I changed the type to "DATE".  It's interesting that in other examples where folks want to show todays date and beyond, they use a "Numeric" type. I guess it makes some sense, but I'm going to jump into the Codex to understand this more. I appreciate all of your help. Here is the solution that works:

```
                        <?php // Let's get the data we need to loop through below
                            $args = array( 
                                    'post_type' => 'carillon', // Tell WordPress which post type we want
                                    'orderby' => 'meta_value', // We want to organize the events by date    
                                    'meta_key' => 'date_of_lighting', // Grab the "date_of_event" field created via "date-picker" plugin (stored in ‘YYYYMMDD’)
                                    'posts_per_page' => '1', // Let's show just one post.   
                                    'meta_query' => array( // WordPress has all the results, now, return only the event for today's date
                                        array(
                                            'key' => 'date_of_lighting', // Check the s"date_of_lighting field
                                            'value' => date("Y-m-d"), // Set today's date (note the similar format)
                                            'compare' => '=', // Return only today's post
                                            'type' => 'DATE' // Let WordPress know we're working with a date
                                            )
                                        )
                                );
```

Comment: `getdate()` with no `timestamp` parameter given returns the array for the current local time. It looks like you don't have any posts for the day you specify in the `'date_query'`.

Comment: You need a `meta_query`. Look at the codex at the custom field parameters  in `WP_Query`. Just a note, your date **MUST BE** saved as `Y-m-d` format  or unix timestamp, any other format will **NOT** work, and then the date you pass as meta value **MUST MATCH** the fomat in which the field is saved otherwise this will also not work. There is really tons of info on-site as well, so be sure to use the site search as well

Comment: Thanks guys. I have updated the code, but it still doesn't work. Please see the original but now amended post. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, you should use `meta_query`.

For help on how to query posts by ACF meta field, you can check the ACF documentation:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'event',
    'meta_key'      => 'location',
    'meta_value'    => 'Melbourne'
);


// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution folks. I've commented on each line to clarify what's going on. Hopefully, it all makes sense and is correct :)

I appreciate the help I received from this rockstar community.

```
        <?php // Let's get the data we need to loop through below
    $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'carillon', // Tell WordPress which post type we want
            'orderby' => 'meta_value', // We want to organize the events by date    
            'meta_key' => 'date_of_lighting', // Grab the "date_of_event" field created via "date-picker" plugin (stored in ‘YYYYMMDD’)
            'posts_per_page' => '1', // Let's show just one post.   
            'meta_query' => array( // WordPress has all the results, now, return only the event for today's date
                array(
                    'key' => 'date_of_lighting', // Check the "date_of_lighting" field
                    'value' => date("Y-m-d"), // Set today's date (note the similar format)
                    'compare' => '=', // Return only today's post
                    'type' => 'DATE' // Let WordPress know we're working with numbers
                      )
                    )
                  );

                        $the_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>

                            <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>                                  

                                    <!-- the loop-->
```